# UITextView tableHeaderView Intrinsic Height

Tags: uitableview, autolayout, uitextview, autoresizingmask, contentsize

I've created programmatically (without Story Board or Interface Builder) a custom subclass of `UITableViewController` called `FooTableViewController`.

In `viewDidLoad`, I've set `tableView.tableHeaderView` to an uneditable `UITextView` with an arbitrary height of `200` and with its `text` set to a random `String`.

The `UITextView` automatically updates its width when I rotate the device. How do I get it to automatically update its height when I set its `text` (so that it exactly contains its `text`)?

Note: I'm using an uneditable `UITextView` instead of a `UILabel` because I want the user to be able to select and copy text.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the relevant instance methods of `FooTableViewController`.

```
// MARK: - UIViewController

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect.zero, textContainer: nil)
    textView.editable = false
    textView.font = .systemFontOfSize(17)
    textView.scrollEnabled = false
    textView.scrollsToTop = false
    textView.text = "Random long string"
    textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 12, bottom: 25, right: 12)
    tableView.tableHeaderView = textView
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    updateTableHeaderViewHeightForWidth(view.frame.width)
}

// MARK: - UIContentContainer

override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({ _ in self.updateTableHeaderViewHeightForWidth(size.width) }, completion: nil)
}

// MARK: - Helpers

func updateTableHeaderViewHeightForWidth(width: CGFloat) {
    let textView = tableView.tableHeaderView!
    let oldHeight = textView.frame.height
    let newHeight = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.max)).height
    textView.frame.size.height = newHeight
    tableView.contentSize.height += newHeight - oldHeight
}
```